# Help using recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a class `Group`. In the class I have two fields, `idGroup` `IdGroupGroup`. Groups may be part of other groups. My class `Group` is defined in a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`; the key is `IdGroupGroup` and value is `idGroup`. I want to search the map for a particular `idGroup`; can I use recursion to do this?

```
class Group
{

    int idGroupe
    String word
}

HashMap<Integer,Integer> GroupeGroupe = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
GroupeGroupe.put(idGroupeGroupe, idGroupe)
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the class?

Comment: If you're mapping `IdGroupGroup` to `idGroup` and you need to search for `idGroup`, you're probably using the wrong data structure

Comment: class Group
{
 int idGroup
 int idGroupGroup
}

Comment: Example i have a Group A and Group B in the Group A i can add an another Group B

Comment: How can you have "Groups may be part of other groups." if the only member of a group is an int?

Comment: And `IdGroupGroup` is what we would call the ID of the object/group, while `idGroup` is possibly another `Group`'s ID (`idGroupGroup`)?

Comment: i have two table the first Group (id and wording) and a second table GroupGroup with id and Idgroup

Comment: That's not what you posted above when you gave the definition of `Group`.  Can you just edit your question with all relevant code (both classes, and your `HashMap`, etc)?

Comment: What does the mapping represent? If this mapping represent child to parent relationship, then you can efficiently look for the parent of a given node. If you want the children of a given node, you will have to maintain a reverse mapping from group id to a set of ids of its children.

Comment: yes map represent parent and child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a vague question, I have to guess a lot, but perhaps it's something like this you're looking for:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    static Map<Integer, Integer> groups = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        groups.put(1, 2);
        groups.put(2, 3);
        groups.put(2, 4);
        groups.put(4, 5);
        System.out.println(searchFor(1, 5));
    }

    private static String searchFor(int from, int target) {

        // Target found?
        if (from == target) return "" + target;

        // Dead end?
        if (!groups.containsKey(from)) return null;

        // Recurse and try to find it from here.
        String path = searchFor(groups.get(from), target);
        return path == null ? null : from + " -> " + path;
    }
}
```

**Output:**
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5

---

Or something like this:

```
    static Map<Integer, Group> groups = new HashMap<Integer, Group>();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        groups.put(0, new Group(1, "hello")); // (0: -)       -> (1: "hello")
        groups.put(2, new Group(9, "!"));     // (2: "world") -> (9, "!")
        groups.put(3, new Group(5, "bye"));   // (3: -)       -> (5, "bye")
        groups.put(1, new Group(2, "world")); // (1: "hello") -> (2: "world")
        System.out.println(traverse(0));
    }

    private static String traverse(int from) {
        if (!groups.containsKey(from)) return "";

        String path = traverse(groups.get(from).idGroupe);
        return path == null ? null : groups.get(from).word + " " + path;
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
hello world !
```

Comment: just search for the first element (key) of yur map
example search for 1
Output->1 have 2 , 2 is a Key and have 3 and stop because 3 is not a key of map

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try to answer.
Do I understand you correctly if you have a java HashMap with entries ?
In that case you only have one entry for each idGroupGroup (java api):

```
   public V put(K key,V value)
```

> Associates the specified value with
>   the specified key in this map. If the
>   map previously contained a mapping for
>   the key, the old value is replaced.

if this is fine, and you just want to do a recursion of all element you can use:

```
public Collection<V> values()
```

> Returns a Collection view of the
>   values contained in this map. The
>   collection is backed by the map, so
>   changes to the map are reflected in
>   the collection, and vice-versa. If the
>   map is modified while an iteration
>   over the collection is in progress
>   (except through the iterator's own
>   remove operation), the results of the
>   iteration are undefined. The
>   collection supports element removal,
>   which removes the corresponding
>   mapping from the map, via the
>   Iterator.remove, Collection.remove,
>   removeAll, retainAll and clear
>   operations. It does not support the
>   add or addAll operations.

have a look at:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

cheers, 
Jørgen